# How to format seconds as integer into HH:MM:SS in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table as:

```
id   time_seconds
5             140
6               5
7           15000
```

I want to get it as:

```
id  time_format
5         23:52
6         00:05
7      04:10:00
```

Basically format of `HH:MM:SS`
Now the thing is that I don't have many records with hours so the `HH:` should be in the output only if there are hours. Otherwise it should be just `MM:SS`

Presto has function that does similar thing
`SELECT parse_duration('60s');` 
But the output isn't what I need
`0 00:01:00.000`
and I'm not sure this is the way to use it?

This is what I did so far:

```
select id, concat(cast(time_seconds as varchar(10)),'s')
from mytable
```

not sure how to continue

Answer (score 2):

You can readily convert this to a time:

```
select time '00:00:00' + time_seconds * interval '1' second
```

I think that that is the best way to represent the value.  Adding the hour conditionally seems like a bad idea -- it can lead to confusion.

I think the following will work on times:

```
select (case when time_seconds < 60 * 60
             then date_format(time '00:00:00' + time_seconds * interval '1' second, '%i:%s')
             else date_format(time '00:00:00' + time_seconds * interval '1' second, '%H:%i:%s')
        end) as hhmmss
```

Comment: mismatched input 'else'. ?

Comment: I think missing ) at the then and else

Comment: I'm also getting Unexpected parameters (time, varchar(5)) for function date_format. Expected: date_format(timestamp, varchar(x))

Comment: How to you handle duration that is greater than 86400 seconds?

Comment: @hkravitz . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a particularly elegant approach, but it'll produce the targeted output format.

Without dropping the potential `'00:'` hours portion:

```
select regexp_replace(concat(
   cast(round(time_seconds/3600) as varchar),':',
   cast(round((time_seconds%3600)/60) as varchar),':',
   cast(round((time_seconds%3600)%60) as varchar)
),'(\d+)(:|\b)', match -> if(length(match)=1,'0'||match[1],match[1]) || match[2])
```

If `'00:'` hours must be dropped, then one could wrap the above in an additional: `regexp_replace(<THE_INNER_RESULT>,'(^00:)(.*)','$2')`.

*Note: This also doesn't satisfy the possible case of `time_seconds>86400` (handling `days`) which `@hkravitz` points out in their comment.*